# better CJK font for Chrome browser on Ubuntu Xenial?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I installed Ubuntu Xenial and Chrome recently.
I noted the default font for CJS is very hard to read.
How do I tweak this?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean CJK (typo?). If yes, you may try to use noto fonts by selecting

`Chrome-> Settings -> Show advanced settings... -> Customize fonts -> Noto (for example, Noto Sans Mono CJK TC, I use this one and looks good)`

If the font does not change after selecting Noto,
you may consider to remove the default font by

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming
```